# Best practice for database connection via Doctrine in a Symfony Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, bundle

In my bundle i create a separate database connection and an EntityManager for it. Everything works fine, except those two things don't show up in the development profiler. There is only the default EntityManager and the default connection.

So basically i created 3 new service definitions for an Doctrine\Common\EventManager, an Doctrine\DBAL\Connection and an Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager. I've already tried to add these new service definition to the ContainerBuilder with the same naming convention which is used by the doctrine bridge, but they still won't show up in the profiler. The connection works fine, but i want debug it with and integrate it in the Symfony lifecycle.

The question is:

**What is the best practice to create a separate database connection via Doctrine inside of a Symfony Bundle if the Symfony application is only configured to support one connection?**

Comment: Well, there is a whole documentation page about that [How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). In general you can assume the Symfony Documentation to be the _best practice_ because it mostly provides the simplest and shortest way to do things.

Comment: Also FIRST google things and only start building complex logic yourself only when you 100% sure there is no general solution...

Comment: @goulashsoup thank you for responding. I've already saw this documentation, but this assumes that doctrine is already configured for several connections. In my case, the symfony applications is configured for a single connection.

Comment: @goulashsoup hm, good question

Comment: I have read the comment below on the answer. So you have to bundles with different database configurations correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should take a look at this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). They described there how to add another EntityManager, which mean another connection. First step is to create configuration.

Especialy take a look at doctrine.yaml configuration:

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            default_connection: default
            connections:
                default:
                    # configure these for your database server
                    url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
                    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                    server_version: '5.7'
                    charset: utf8mb4
                customer:
                    # configure these for your database server
                    url: '%env(DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
                    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                    server_version: '5.7'
                    charset: utf8mb4
        orm:
            default_entity_manager: default
            entity_managers:
                default:
                    connection: default
                    mappings:
                        Main:
                            is_bundle: false
                            type: annotation
                            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                            prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                            alias: Main
                customer:
                    connection: customer
                    mappings:
                        Customer:
                            is_bundle: false
                            type: annotation
                            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customer'
                            prefix: 'App\Entity\Customer'
                            alias: Customer
```

Above are two entity managers, 'default' and 'customer'. There are also two cennections, one for each manager.

If configuration is valid you will have access to those managers by passing its names to 'getManager' method.

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
$customerEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer');
```

**If you cant edit configuration:**
What what about creating custom class (Manager or something) in which you will manually create connection. Take a look at this, it should help you. 
[getting-a-connection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/configuration.html#getting-a-connection)

Comment: hello @igor thank you for responding! The thing is, that the symfony application is already configured for only one database connection and i want to add a separate one for my bundle and via the bundle. Those docs don't fullfill the requirement.